# Django storages S3 - Store existing file

Tags: django, boto3, wagtail, python-django-storages

I have django 1.11 with latest django-storages, setup with S3 backend.

I am trying to programatically instantiate an ImageFile, using the AWS image link as a starting point. I cannot figure out how to do this looking at the source / documentation.

I assume I need to create a file, and give it the path derived from the url without the domain, but I can't find exactly how.

The final aim of this is to programatically create wagtail `Image` objects, that point to S3 images (So pass the new ImageFile to the Imagefield of the image). I own the S3 bucket the images are stored in it.

Uploading images works correctly, so the system is setup correctly.

**Update**

To clarify, I need to do the reverse of the normal process. Normally a physical image is given to the system, which then creates a `ImageFile`, the file is then uploaded to S3, and a URL is assigned to the `File.url`. I have the `File.url` and need an `ImageFile` object.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out, in several models that expect files, when using DjangoStorages, all I had to do is instead of passing a `File` on the file field, pass the AWS S3 object key (so not a URL, just the object key).
When `model.save()` is called, a `boto` call is made to S3 to verify an object with the provided key is there, and the item is saved.

Comment: For clarification this means: `my_model.upload = "s3 object key.jpg"` instead of `my_model.upload.save(...)`

Comment: I'm attempting to do the exact same thing, but I'm getting an error. djfile = Media.objects.create(asset_title='Title 1", image_file=my_bucket_object) generates an AttributeError: 's3.ObjectSummary' object has no attribute '_committed'