# How to programmatically store S3 images in Django

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto3, python-django-storages

As noted in this previous question linked here, I am doing the reverse of saving images in Django that get uploaded to S3. The images already reside in S3 and I want to programmatically add the images to Django by creating media objects.

[Django storages S3 - Store existing file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609686/django-storages-s3-store-existing-file)

My class looks like this:

```
class Media( models.Model ):
    asset_title = models.CharField( 'Title', max_length=255, help_text='The title of this asset.' )
    image_file = models.ImageField( upload_to='upload/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True )
```

In my view, I have this:

```
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')

for my_bucket_object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='media/upload/2020'):
    djfile = Media.objects.create(asset_title=my_bucket_object.key, image_file=my_bucket_object)
```

I'm currently getting an AttributeError: 's3.ObjectSummary' object has no attribute '_committed'

Answer (score 2):

`s3.ObjectSummary` object may not be identified as an image object by Django.

Give this a try

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile

bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')

for my_bucket_object in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='media/upload/2020'):
    djfile = Media.objects.create(asset_title=my_bucket_object.key, image_file=ContentFile(my_bucket_object))
```

> The ContentFile class inherits from File, but unlike File, it operates
> on string content (bytes also supported), rather than an actual file
> [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class)